# How to start Azure Storage Emulator under non-admin account

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I can't get Azure Storage Emulator to start. I am running v4.6.

I have two accounts on my dev machine, the Administrator account (which I don't use) and my named account gregv. I do all my development work under the gregv account.

This means that the Administrator account does not have access to SqlLocalDB. I have tested this by logging into the Administrator account and starting up SMSS and trying to attach to (localdb)\v11.0. I can connect when I am logged in as gregv but I can't when I am logged in as Administrator.

I think that Azure Storage Emulator is trying to set itself up as if the Administrator account was the one doing the running. I think this because it is creating the mdf database files under c:\Users\Administrator not under c:\Users\gregv, even when I install it when logged in as gregv.

When I try to run the emulator, it hangs for a while then finally gives me this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>AzureStorageEmulator.exe start
Windows Azure Storage Emulator 4.6.0.0 command line tool

Unhandled Exception: System.TimeoutException: Unable to open wait handle.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Controller.EmulatorProcessController.InternalWaitForStorageEmulator(Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Controller.EmulatorProcessController.EnsureRunning(Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Commands.StartCommand.RunCommand()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Any suggestions on how I can get this running as the user gregv? Or should I be ditching the gregv account and move over to do all my development as Administrator?

Update: I have shared the v11.0 instance as user gregv and now I can connect to the lcoaldb database using SSMS when I am logged in as Administrator. I can also successfully start up the Emulator when I am logged in as Administrator now.

But when I log out of the Administrator account and log in as gregv, I can't start up the emulator. I really want to do my development work under my non-administrator account, which means I have to get access to the emulator from that account.

Comment: I think the issue might be related to the fact that the gregv account has read and write permissions to c:\Users\Administrator. I think that might be messing up the detection logic in the emulator as to where to put the database files.

Comment: No that wasn't it. I removed permissions for gregv to read the administrator folder and it still put the mdf file in the Administrator folder and then failed to startup.

Comment: where's the logic, to put the file into the directory, you don't need read permissions...

Comment: Please try to run your command line tool as administrator. then run `AzureStorageEmulator.exe start`. Please also know that we must have administrative privileges to configure Azure emulator. Refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-emulator) for more details.

Comment: You need to initialize the emulator as the user that be running the emulator. Initialization requires elevation, so you will need to temporarily elevate the user account itself (and not run as the Administrator account). After this one-time setup you can run without elevation. We're looking into improving the emulator's support for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by @Jambor and @Michael Roberson, the trick was to "run as administrator" on the command shell I was launching to run the azure storage command.

once i did that once, was able to use the azure storage emulator from my normal account.

Comment: I am revisiting this because I had to restart my dev machine today and I couldn't get the Azure storage emulator to start again without running it from an Admin enabled command prompt. I see that the expectation is that you only have to do the init once as an admin, but my experience is that you have to always start it up as an admin.